# Enforcing the C++98 standard in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, c++98

I have a school assignment that should be written in C++98-compliant code. How can I force `g++` to accept only code that follows this standard? Will `-std=c++98` do the trick or do I need to add additional flags?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Per [GCC's documentation on standards](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html):

> The original ISO C++ standard was published as the ISO standard (ISO/IEC 14882:1998) and amended by a Technical Corrigenda published in 2003 (ISO/IEC 14882:2003). These standards are referred to as C++98 and C++03, respectively. GCC implements the majority of C++98 (export is a notable exception) and most of the changes in C++03. To select this standard in GCC, use one of the options -ansi, -std=c++98, or -std=c++03; to obtain all the diagnostics required by the standard, you should also specify -pedantic (or -pedantic-errors if you want them to be errors rather than warnings).

Therefore, you should specify `-std=c++98 -pedantic` if you really want to ensure standards compliance.

Comment: +1, but as it says you should use `-pedantic-errors` to *ensure* compliance (as far as gcc is able). `-pedantic` merely informs you about non-compliance. Btw, this still won't catch all code that uses implementation-specific assumptions that happen to be true, but that's an argument about what you mean by "compliant code". In the C standard there's a difference between a well-formed program and a strictly conforming program, the same difference applies to C++ but I don't think the C++ standard uses the term "strictly conforming program".

Comment: @SteveJessop: What is that difference?

Comment: @KerreK: from memory, a well-formed program is one that obeys all the constraints, whereas a strictly conforming program is one that has defined behavior, and this behavior is the same on all conforming implementations. Probably what an instructor means by "C++98-compliant" is that the program is well-formed and has defined behavior *on GCC in pedantic mode*, that is to say it's not necessarily portable.

Comment: Just looked it up, the exact text is in C99 4/5, "A strictly conforming program shall use only those features of the language and library
speciﬁed in this International Standard.
It shall not produce output dependent on any
unspeciﬁed, undeﬁned, or implementation-deﬁned behavior,and shall not exceed any
minimum implementation limit". I'm actually not sure whether that means that for example it cannot rely on `malloc` succeeding. In effect it's unspecified whether a given memory allocation succeeds or not, but that's not the exact language under `malloc`.

Comment: Hm, I suspect it would be intractable to actually prove a program conforming according to that definition, since some UB depends on the exact values of variables involved (e.g. UB involving accessing invalid array elements). So `-pedantic` really is the best you can do (at least with GCC).

Comment: @nnoeonneo: agreed, it's definitely a halting problem to prove in general whether a program causes UB. If you write a program that eventually crashes if and only if the Riemann hypothesis is false, the prof has quite a task to decide whether to give you the marks for "code doesn't crash" ;-) Basically, GCC will check that what you've said makes sense in the language, it can also warn for a few other common issues, but then you're on your own as to the behavior of what you said.

Comment: The important point for the questioner being: using `-pedantic-errors` is a start, but it's not a safety-net. You also have to code carefully. You might find that if you assume that `char` has 8 bits then the prof marks you down for writing non-portable code, or you might find that's allowed, but either way GCC won't warn you that the standard permits `CHAR_BIT` to be bigger than 8.