# GCC: emit warnings when c++11 is used

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++98

#### Given

Cross-platform C++ project that has to build on some ancient windows mobile platforms. However the development is done with GCC.

#### Problem

Every time that C++11 feature is used it will build locally but fail on the build server (mobile windows).

#### Question

Is it possible to configure GCC to somehow warn if C++11 feature is used in our code-base (excluding other source-dependencies).

#### What have you tried?

I know about using [`-std=c++98 -pedantic`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606713/enforcing-the-c98-standard-in-gcc), but:

1. I would like to use the latest compiler standard on Linux platform
2. There are some linux-only third-party dependencies (build from the source) that require C++11

Comment: perhaps build the server part with `-std=c++98` and the dependencies separately with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: Are you looking for `-Wc++11-compat`?

Comment: @StoryTeller could you provide any docs link please?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options

Comment: @StoryTeller no, I'm afraid it does not do what I want. E.g., it does not warn if `auto` is used. It only works if used together with `-std=c++98`

Answer (score 0):

Build the code you need to be C++98 compatible using C++98 flags.

Build the code you need to be C++11 compatible using C++11 flags.

Examine the documentation of the compiler and standard library used to ensure ABI compatibility between code built with C++98 and C++11; you may have to (for example) use C++98 strings in your C++11 code in order to have ABI compatibility, assuming you pass `std::string`s between the C++98 and C++11 code bases.

You cannot both use C++11 and not use C++11 when building the same file, unless you build it twice.  Which is also an option; build the C++98 compatible stuff twice, once with C++latest and once with C++98.  Throw away the C++98 build after halting on errors and warnings.